# Read only access to all kubernetes objects in an EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

My requirement is to provide read-only access to all objects of Kubernetes in the EKS cluster to certain IAM users. These objects can be nodes, pods, services, replica sets, daemonset, etc.

I referred the docs but haven't found what is the best way.
What I did is create an IAM role with the name `read-only-access-eks` which has the policy `ReadOnlyAccess` attached to it. This is a managed policy.

I attached this policy to one of the IAM users on my team, but when he logged in to the EKS cluster, he got the below error:

> Error loading GenericResourceCollection/namespaces
>
> namespaces is forbidden: User "xxxxx" cannot list
> resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope

How to fix this?

**UPDATE 1**

here is the output of

```
kubectl edit -n kube-system configmap/aws-auth
```

output

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - groups:
      - system:bootstrappers
      - system:nodes
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::02334:role/AmazonEKSVPCCNIRole
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
  mapUsers: |
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::02334:user/user1
      username: user1
      groups:
        - view
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::02334:user/user2
      username: user2
      groups:
        - system:masters
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-04-13T14:27:20Z"
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "357187"
  uid: 58a534550-bcc-44f-2d6-15435435
```

I see that the user1 is a part of the view group, then still he is getting an access denied error. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the `aws-auth configmap` (in the `kube-system` namespace) and add the `mapUsers` section to add the IAM user you need to provide with read-only access to see/view (most) objects in the Cluster.

The configuration you need to add shall look something like this:

```
data:
  mapUsers: |
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/read-only-access-eks
      username: read-only-access-eks
      groups:
        - view
```

where `view` is the default `ClusterRole` which allows read-only access to see most objects in a namespace. Read more about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#user-facing-roles)

[Here](https://www.agilepartner.net/en/adding-users-to-your-eks-cluster/) is another link that should guide you to map an IAM user arn to a pre-defined `ClusterRole`.

Some [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html) around `aws-auth ConfigMap` in an eks cluster.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I did the same in the aws-ath config map , but it is not working . Please see the UPDATE 1

Comment: Thanks . it worked. actually , after following the doc , things cleared

Comment: Glad to know. What was the reason for it not working earlier? Just to understand what are the possibilities of where it could go wrong.